# Add prefixes to ostream outputs

Tags: c++, gcc, iostream, apache-sentry

I am looking for a way of adding a prefix to an ostream, pass it down to other functions so that their outputs are prefixed and then remove it to continue.

Check the following pseudocode:

```
...
void function(ostream &out){
    out << "output 1\n";
    out << "output 2\n";
}

cout << "Whatever\n";
add_suffix(cout,"function: ");
function(cout);
remove_suffix(cout);
...
```

With an output like:

```
...
Whatever
function: output 1
function: output 2
...
```

Looking at the docs of ostream they state that sentry might be used for prefixing/suffixing but i don't know how to do this if the intended use is what I want.

The `ostream::sentry` documentation says:

```
sentry: Perform exception safe prefix/suffix operations
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The general way goes like this: Define `YourStreamBuffer` that is a `streambuf` that inserts your prefix after any newline that is written to it, and sends the output to a destination buffer. Then use it like this:

```
streambuf *oldBuf = cout.rdbuf();

YourStreamBuffer yourBuf(oldBuf, "function: ");
// everything written to yourBuf is sent to oldBuf

cout.rdbuf(&yourBuf);
function(cout);
cout.rdbuf(oldBuf);
```

You can find plenty examples on the net on how to implement your stream buffers.
Also make sure that your code is exception safe, that is restore oldBuf even if an exception is thrown.

Note: sentries are something different, it's not what you need here.

Comment: I am aware about streambufs and that was my original idea, i was just wondering why the sentry is documented like that if it doesn't do such a thing.

Comment: @Arkaitz: "prefix" that is mentioned there is a prefix of a function that reads/writes to the stream. They are meant to check the state of the stream and throw exceptions when the stream is in bad-state.

Comment: cool, now it makes sense, its just that prefix and suffix operations on a stream context did look too much like what I wanted, I guess I'm tied to the streambuf implementation then.

Answer (score 0):

Alternatively, you could use an evil macro for this..

```
#define f_str(str) str << __FUNCTION__ << ' '
```

(yes, `__FUNCTION__` isn't defined everywhere, but hey...) Negtive is that you have to use the macro to wrap, positive is that it only inserts the name once for all chained stream operations (in the stream buffer case, it'll have a prefix for all new lines [unless that's what you want of course!])